Using array formula to join all matches in a cell
I am using google sheets and found a formula that works but I have to drag it down 1000s of rows which is making the sheet super slow/unuseable.
Basically I want to join all matches into a single cell.  I am hoping array formula can be used somehow.



ColA
Col K




1
Value 1


1
Value 2


1
Value 3


1
Value 4


2
Value 2


2
Value 4


2
Value 1



If cell A24 contains "1" then return
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
Value 4
All in one cell
If cell A24 contains "2" then return
Value 2
Value 4
Value 1
All in one cell
Hope I am explaining ok
This is what I have but have to drag...
=arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(Char(10), TRUE, IF(IFERROR(MATCH($K$4:$K, IF(A24=$A$4:$A,$K$4:$K,""),0),"")=MATCH(ROW($A$4:$A),ROW($B$4:$B)),$K$4:$K,"")))


You may try:
=map(A4:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,textjoin(char(10),1,ifna(filter(K:K,A:A=Σ))))))



This is great! Works exactly as I explained it! Is there anyway to make it not repeat duplicates? I forgot that piece.

change this part filter(K:K,A:A=Σ) to unique(filter(K:K,A:A=Σ))

wow rocking freak show! saved the day! Thanks!
